# PHP Regex Negative Lookahead with enters

Tags: php, regex, json

I'm trying to scrape a .JSON file however the returned file returns multiple JSON objects in 1 .json file, resulting in a invalid json file. I'm trying to solve this by adding a [ before the JSON file and a ] after the json file. Then using a regex to add comma at the right places.

This is the file before the regex

```
[{"status":"success"}

{"values":{"cpu":26.5152886753948387,"ram":0.8452846061135513},"origin":"core","type":-1,"uuid":"0000-e8-de-27-176d10"}

{"values":{"cpu":25.5839236550189568,"ram":0.8452846061135513},"origin":"core","type":-1,"uuid":"0000-e8-de-27-176d10"}

]
```

I created the following regex: `}(?!\s,|\s])`.
The problem I have is that it is still adding a , after the last } even though it's followed by a ].

What I'm getting:

```
[{"status":"success"},

{"values":{"cpu":26.5152886753948387,"ram":0.8452846061135513},"origin":"core","type":-1,"uuid":"0000-e8-de-27-176d10"},

{"values":{"cpu":25.5839236550189568,"ram":0.8452846061135513},"origin":"core","type":-1,"uuid":"0000-e8-de-27-176d10"},

]
```

Expected result:

```
[{"status":"success"},

{"values":{"cpu":26.5152886753948387,"ram":0.8452846061135513},"origin":"core","type":-1,"uuid":"0000-e8-de-27-176d10"},

{"values":{"cpu":25.5839236550189568,"ram":0.8452846061135513},"origin":"core","type":-1,"uuid":"0000-e8-de-27-176d10"}

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `\s` in your regex with `\s*` since `\s` will match a single space character where `\s*` would match zero or more space characters.

```
}(?!\s*[,\]])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fZ6eX3/1)

```
$re = "/}(?!\\s*[,\\]])/m";
$str = "[{\"status\":\"success\"}\n\n{\"values\":{\"cpu\":26.5152886753948387,\"ram\":0.8452846061135513},\"origin\":\"core\",\"type\":-1,\"uuid\":\"0000-e8-de-27-176d10\"}\n\n{\"values\":{\"cpu\":25.5839236550189568,\"ram\":0.8452846061135513},\"origin\":\"core\",\"type\":-1,\"uuid\":\"0000-e8-de-27-176d10\"}\n\n]";
$subst = "},";
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```